# Linux, out of memory in bash script, not interactive, not ulimit?

Tags: c, linux, bash, memory

What linux settings could result in a C++ program run as:

```
jellyfish count -m 31 -t 40 -C -s 105  -o k_u_hash_0 pe.cor.fa
```

working fine when that command is executed in a terminal, but crashing in a bash script?  In the latter case it asks for 411428571480 bytes before it exits - immediately.  This is odd because when run interactively **top** shows it with just 10's of Gb of  Virt and Res memory many minutes after it started running.

```
ulimit -a
```

in both environments shows:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 2067197
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

/proc/meminfo shows:

```
CommitLimit:    615693660 kB
Committed_AS:   48320500 kB
```

and even stranger, a small C test program, which just calloc's ever larger memory blocks than releases them, when run in either environment, including immediately before jellyfish, did this:

```
calloc_test
Testing 4294967296
Testing 8589934592
Testing 17179869184
Testing 34359738368
Testing 68719476736
Testing 137438953472
Testing 274877906944
Testing 549755813888
Testing 1099511627776
FAILED
```

That is, it was able to allocate a 549 Gb block, which is larger than the one jellyfish asked for, and memory allocation behaved the same in both environments.

There is no **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** set in either case.

Can anybody suggest what might differ in the two environments to account for the difference in the action of a subset of memory allocating programs?  (A subset of one at this point.)

Thank you.

As requested, this is the script (only down to the point of failure plus 3 extra lines):

```
#!/bin/bash

# assemble.sh generated by masurca
CONFIG_PATH="/home/mathog/do_masurca/project.cfg"
CMD_PATH="/home/mathog/MaSuRCA/bin/masurca"

# Test that we support <() redirection
(eval "cat <(echo test) >/dev/null" 2>/dev/null) || {
  echo >&2 "ERROR: The shell used is missing important features."
  echo >&2 "       Run the assembly script directly as './$0'"
  exit 1
}

# Parse command line switches
while getopts ":rc" o; do
  case "${o}" in
    c)
    echo "configuration file is '$CONFIG_PATH'"
    exit 0
    ;;
    r)
    echo "Rerunning configuration"
    exec perl "$CMD_PATH" "$CONFIG_PATH"
    echo "Failed to rerun configuration"
    exit 1
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 [-r] [-c]"
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done
set +e
# Set some paths and prime system to save environment variables
save () {
  (echo -n "$1=\""; eval "echo -n \"\$$1\""; echo '"') >> environment.sh
}
GC=
RC=
NC=
if tty -s < /dev/fd/1 2> /dev/null; then
  GC='\e[0;32m'
  RC='\e[0;31m'
  NC='\e[0m'
fi
log () {
  d=$(date)
  echo -e "${GC}[$d]${NC} $@"
}
fail () {
  d=$(date)
  echo -e "${RC}[$d]${NC} $@"
  exit 1
}
signaled () {
  fail Interrupted
}
trap signaled TERM QUIT INT
rm -f environment.sh; touch environment.sh

# To run tasks in parallel
run_bg () {
  semaphore -j $NUM_THREADS --id masurca_$$ -- "$@"
}
run_wait () {
  semaphore -j $NUM_THREADS --id masurca_$$ --wait
}
export PATH="/home/mathog/MaSuRCA/bin:/home/mathog/MaSuRCA/bin/../CA/Linux-amd64/bin:$PATH"
save PATH
export PERL5LIB=/home/mathog/MaSuRCA/bin/../lib/perl${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}
save PERL5LIB
NUM_THREADS=40
save NUM_THREADS
log 'Processing pe library reads'
rm -rf meanAndStdevByPrefix.pe.txt
echo 'pe 400 20' >> meanAndStdevByPrefix.pe.txt
run_bg rename_filter_fastq 'pe' <(exec expand_fastq '/home/mathog/SPUR_datasets/pe_400_R1.fastq' | awk '{if(length($0>200)) print substr($0,1,200); else print $0;}') <(exec expand_fastq '/home/mathog/SPUR_datasets/pe_400_R2.fastq' | awk '{if(length($0>200)) print substr($0,1,200); else print $0;}' ) > 'pe.renamed.fastq'
run_wait

head -q -n 40000  pe.renamed.fastq | grep --text -v '^+' | grep --text -v '^@' > pe_data.tmp
export PE_AVG_READ_LENGTH=`awk '{if(length($1)>31){n+=length($1);m++;}}END{print int(n/m)}' pe_data.tmp`
save PE_AVG_READ_LENGTH
echo "Average PE read length $PE_AVG_READ_LENGTH"
KMER=`for f in pe.renamed.fastq;do head -n 80000 $f |tail -n 40000;done | perl -e 'while($line=<STDIN>){$line=<STDIN>;chomp($line);push(@lines,$line);$line=<STDIN>;$line=<STDIN>}$min_len=100000;$base_count=0;foreach $l(@lines){$base_count+=length($l);push(@lengths,length($l));@f=split("",$l);foreach $base(@f){if(uc($base) eq "G" || uc($base) eq "C"){$gc_count++}}} @lengths =sort {$b <=> $a} @lengths; $min_len=$lengths[int($#lengths*.75)];  $gc_ratio=$gc_count/$base_count;$kmer=0;if($gc_ratio<0.5){$kmer=int($min_len*.7);}elsif($gc_ratio>=0.5 && $gc_ratio<0.6){$kmer=int($min_len*.5);}else{$kmer=int($min_len*.33);} $kmer++ if($kmer%2==0); $kmer=31 if($kmer<31); $kmer=127 if($kmer>127); print $kmer'`
save KMER
echo "choosing kmer size of $KMER for the graph"
KMER_J=$KMER
MIN_Q_CHAR=`cat pe.renamed.fastq |head -n 50000 | awk 'BEGIN{flag=0}{if($0 ~ /^\+/){flag=1}else if(flag==1){print $0;flag=0}}'  | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$q0_char="@";}{chomp;@f=split "";foreach $v(@f){if(ord($v)<ord($q0_char)){$q0_char=$v;}}}END{$ans=ord($q0_char);if($ans<64){print "33\n"}else{print "64\n"}}'`
save MIN_Q_CHAR
echo MIN_Q_CHAR: $MIN_Q_CHAR
JF_SIZE=`ls -l *.fastq | awk '{n+=$5}END{s=int(n/50); if(s>80000000000)printf "%.0f",s;else print "80000000000";}'`
save JF_SIZE
perl -e '{if(int('$JF_SIZE')>80000000000){print "WARNING: JF_SIZE set too low, increasing JF_SIZE to at least '$JF_SIZE', this automatic increase may be not enough!\n"}}'
log Creating mer database for Quorum.
quorum_create_database -t 40 -s $JF_SIZE -b 7 -m 24 -q $((MIN_Q_CHAR + 5)) -o quorum_mer_db.jf.tmp pe.renamed.fastq && mv quorum_mer_db.jf.tmp quorum_mer_db.jf
if [ 0 != 0 ]; then
  fail Increase JF_SIZE in config file, the recommendation is to set this to genome_size*coverage/2
fi

log Error correct PE.

quorum_error_correct_reads  -q $((MIN_Q_CHAR + 40)) --contaminant=/home/mathog/MaSuRCA/bin/../share/adapter.jf -m 1 -s 1 -g 1 -a 3 -t 40 -w 10 -e 3 -M  quorum_mer_db.jf pe.renamed.fastq --no-discard -o pe.cor --verbose 1>quorum.err 2>&1 || {
  mv pe.cor.fa pe.cor.fa.failed && fail Error correction of PE reads failed. Check pe.cor.log.
}


log Estimating genome size.
jellyfish count -m 31 -t 40 -C -s $JF_SIZE -o k_u_hash_0 pe.cor.fa
export ESTIMATED_GENOME_SIZE=`jellyfish histo -t 40 -h 1 k_u_hash_0 | tail -n 1 |awk '{print $2}'`
save ESTIMATED_GENOME_SIZE
echo "Estimated genome size: $ESTIMATED_GENOME_SIZE"
```

Comment: What is the C++ program? How much memory do you have? Why is this program allocating 10's of GB of memory? Also being able to allocate looots of memory does not mean you are also able to write to all that memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could it be a 32 bit implementation of bash?

Comment: My guess would be an uninitialized variable being negative sometimes and being used for a memory allocation while uninitialized.  Without the code, though, there is no more that anyone can do than speculate.  This is unresolveable until there is more information — that MCVE ([MCVE]) that people ask for.

Comment: It is a 64 bit bash.  The jellyfish program analyzes tuples of a given size in a very large set of DNA sequences.  The input data is roughly 80Gb, and the tuple size is around 21.  So it is going to use a lot of memory.  It isn't entirely clear which version of jellyfish this is as it came with part of another software package called MaSuRCA and identifies its version only as "global 1".  It does appear to be version 2.x of jellyfish though.

Comment: Show us the script.

Comment: re: Jonathan Leffler:  agreed an unitialized variable might indeed act that way.  When that big machine is free again (could be days) I'll try starting it within valgrind, which would catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's (some) useless memory and CPU cycle waste in the script:

```
cat pe.renamed.fastq | head -n 50000 | ...
```

You should instead avoid the useless use of cat with

```
head -n 50000 pe.renamed.fastq | ...
```

Comment: None of this is my code.  I just want to understand why the program is acting the way it does.  That little bit of wasted resources isn't going to matter much here - to run all the way through the script takes days on a 48 CPU machine.  I don't know yet how many days...